# Render pug variable which contains a script tag

Tags: pug, google-tag-manager

I've made lots of research to render a variable containing a Google Analytics tag :

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-******-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-******-1');
</script>
```

I know this is possible :

```
script.
  #{codeAnalytics}
```

But it will print  tags inside  tag.

Is it possible to just use it like :

```
#{codeGTM}
```

And this will print the analytics tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with :

```
.
   !{codeGTM}
```

Note that we need the "!" and not the "#" for the scripts tag to be interpreted as html tags.